# Merging two arrays with models

Tags: php, laravel

So I have a simple table:

```
messages:
 - id
 - user_id - user that "sent" the message (the author)
 - to_user_id - user that "received" the message
 - body
 - created_at
 - updated_at
```

I'm using Laravel 5.2, I have a model that looks like this:

```
class Message extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User'); //This should return only the sender
    }

    public function scopeSentByUser($query, $user_id)
    {
        return $query->where('user_id', '=', $user_id);
    }

    public function scopeReceivedByUser($query, $user_id)
    {
        return $query->orWhere('to_user_id', '=', $user_id);
    }

    public function scopeNewestFirst($query)
    {
        return $query->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
    }
}
```

In my controller I have two variables that call few model methods:

```
$this->sent = Message::sentByUser(Auth::user()->id)->newestFirst()->get();
$this->received = Message::receivedByUser(Auth::user()->id)->newestFirst()->get();
```

I was wondering how can I merge them into threads. Basically I don't have anything like threads in my app. Users can write messages between and it's a single thread. Like Zuckerberg's social network, or Google's chat client.

I want to be able to keep them in order (or I can order them after grouping) and have something like:

```
$threads = [
    [
        'participants' => [1, 2], //those are users' ids
        'messages' => [
            (Model)Message,
            (Model)Message,
            (Model)Message,
            (Model)Message,
            (Model)Message
        ]
    ] 
];
```

**Edit**:

Based on the accepted answer I ended up having the following code:

```
$query = self::where('user_id', $logged_user_id)->orWhere('to_user_id', $logged_user_id)->get();

$inUserId = $query->lists('user_id')->toArray();
$inToUserId = $query->lists('to_user_id')->toArray();

$mergedIds = array_merge($inUserId, $inToUserId);
$uniqueIds = array_unique($mergedIds);

unset($uniqueIds[array_search($logged_user_id, $uniqueIds)]); //Remove logged in user ID

$combinations = [];
foreach ($uniqueIds as $id) {
    $combinations[] = [$id, $logged_user_id];
}
$threads = [];
foreach ($combinations as $key => $combo) {
    $threads[] = [
        'receiver' => $combo[0] == $logged_user_id ? User::find($combo[1]) : User::find($combo[0]),
        'messages' => self::where(function ($query) use ($combo) {
            $query->where('user_id', $combo[0])->where('to_user_id', $combo[1]);
        })->orWhere(function ($query) use ($combo) {
            $query->where('user_id', $combo[1])->where('to_user_id', $combo[0]);
        })->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')->get()
    ];
}

return $threads;
```

The differences are:
`pluck()` is replaced with `lists()->toArray()`

After merging the arrays (`array_merge`) and picking the unique values only (`array_unique`) I unset the logged in user's id. Because I don't need it.

Also, removed that method for getting the distinct pairs, since it's not applicable. I believe it should be working now properly.

Will update after some more complex testing is done.

*Posted this as update, since I cannot edit answers. And my corrections are too few to post my own answer.*

Comment: Where would the other user ID be coming from?

Comment: Well, if I message you it will save my id in `user_id` and yours in `to_user_id`. But if you message me mine will be saved as `to_user_id` and yours as `user_id`.

Comment: So are you wanting, say, a method where you can do `getMessagesSentBetweenUserIds(1, 2)` and it will return your `$threads` array? Or are you trying to get all the messages for all the users at once? Because if you just use your `sentByUser` and `receivedByUser` methods that you have now, you could be potentially pulling in messages from other users outside of 1 and 2 which I don't think you want.

Comment: I want to get all messages that include me (for example) and group them by participants. So if I have sent you 10 messages and have sent John Doe 5 messages I want to have two elements in this `$thread` array that contain my id with yours and an array with the messages between us and one array that contains my id and john doe's id and the 5 message we have exchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. I've written it like a model method, but you can also add it to a controller by changing `$this` to the correct model name.

```
public function getThreads($id) {
    $query = $this->where('user_id', $id)->orWhere('to_user_id', $id)->get();
    // get the unique user id's
    $user_ids = array_unique (array_merge ($query->pluck('user_id'), $query->pluck('to_user_id')));

    // get the distinct pairs
    // taken from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3770452/485418
    $num_ids = count($user_ids);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_ids; $i++)
    {
        for ($j = $i+1; $j < $num_ids; $j++)
        {
            $combinations[] = array($user_ids[$i], $user_ids[$j]);
        }
    }

    $threads = array();
    $tmp = array();
    // build the threads array
    foreach ($combinations as $key => $combo) {
        $tmp = array();
        $tmp['participants'] = $combo;
        $tmp['messages'] = $this->where(function($query) {
                                        $query->where('user_id', $combo[0])->where('to_user_id', $combo[1]);
                                    })->orWhere(function($query) {
                                        $query->where('user_id', $combo[1])->where('to_user_id', $combo[0]);
                                    })->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
        $threads[] = $tmp;
    }

    return $threads
}
```

Comment: I edited `pluck()` to `lists()->toArray()` and made it a static function. I will edit your answer, feel free to revert it if you have any notes.

Comment: Actually, I updated my question with everything I changed to get this working properly (I *think* it's working properly.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that:

```
$messages = array();
foreach ($this->sent as $message) {
    $messages[] = $message;
}
foreach ($this->received as $message) {
    $messages[] = $message;
}
$messages = collect($messages);
$participants = $messages->keyBy('user_id')->keys();
```

If you have collection `$messages` you can use all this methods: https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections